# Black background from transparent image

Tags: php, image, png

I created an image from other image with the following code,

```
 imagepng(imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents(destination path)),source_path);
```

The image was created,But when i try to create a png image from a **transparent**  image,The background become **black** color.

Why this happens?How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [GD Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) you'll find the alpha based functions. Taken directly from [imagesavealpha()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php) is the following code that opens a png and outputs it with transparency maintained;

```
// Load a png image with alpha channels
$png = imagecreatefrompng('./alphachannel_example.png');

// Do required operations
// (So any resizing/rotating/cropping etc)

// Turn off alpha blending and set alpha flag
imagealphablending($png, false);
imagesavealpha($png, true);

// Output image to browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($png);
```